# Does every connection admit a parallel volume form?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, exterior-algebra, connections

Let $E$ be a smooth orientable vector bundle of rank $k$ over a manifold $M$. Let $\nabla$ be a connection on $E$. Does there always exist a non-zero parallel section of $\Lambda_k(E)$?

What about $E=TM$? (when $M$ is orientable)

Comment: I think every metric connection does as its holonomy is contained in $SO(n)$ and $SO(n) \subset SL(n)$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This can also be seen as follows: Let $e_i$ be a positive orthonormal frame for $E$. Then $e_1 \wedge \dots \wedge e_k$ is a parallel section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, in general this is not true. The curvature $R^k$ of the connection $\nabla$ induces on $\Lambda^k E$ can be identified with $(X, Y) \mapsto \operatorname{tr}R^{\nabla}(X, Y) \,\cdot\,$. So, if $\xi$ is a parallel section of $\Lambda^k E$, differentiating $0 = \nabla \xi$ and skewing gives $0 = R^k(X, Y)(\xi) = (\operatorname{tr}R(X, Y)) \xi$. Thus, the following are equivalent:

- $\Lambda^k E$ (locally) admits parallel sections;
- the curvature $R^{\nabla}$ of $\nabla$ takes values in $\Lambda^2 T^*M \otimes \mathfrak{sl}(E)$;
- the curvature $R^k$ of the induced connection vanishes.

It follows that if $\dim M = 1$ or $k = 1$ then $\Lambda^k E$ always (locally) admits parallel sections.

There need not even be a parallel volume form even in the special case $E = TM$---which is the subject of [this converse question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125567/the-other-trace-of-the-curvature-tensor/2125757)---even if we restrict to torsion-free connections. In that setting, applying the (First) Bianchi identity to $\operatorname{tr}R$ implies that the curvature of the induced connection coincides up to a nonzero multiple with the skew-symmetrization $(X, Y) \mapsto \frac{1}{2}[\operatorname{Ric}(X, Y) - \operatorname{Ric}(Y, X)]$ of the Ricci tensor of $\nabla$.

To see that $R^k$ need not automatically vanish, it's enough to carry out a quick local computation. For the torsion-free connection $\nabla$ with Christoffel symbols $\Gamma_{ab}^c = \Gamma_{ba}^c$ in the standard chart on $\Bbb R^2$, the curvature of the induced connection is
$$(\partial_x \Gamma_{xy}^x - \partial_y \Gamma_{xx}^x + \partial_x \Gamma_{yy}^y - \partial_y \Gamma_{xy}^y) \,dx \wedge dy ,$$
and obviously one can choose the $\Gamma_{ab}^c$ so that this quantity is not zero.

As observed in the comments, if $\nabla$ preserves some metric $g$, then it preserves both of its volume forms, because they are constructed from $g$ invariantly (or, just as well, because the curvature of $\nabla$ takes values in $\Lambda^2 T^*M \otimes \mathfrak{so}(g) \subseteq \Lambda^2 T^*M \otimes \mathfrak{sl}(TM)$).

If one is only interested in the (unparameterized) geodesics of a connection $\nabla$ on $TM$, i.e., in the projective structure $[\nabla]$, this is strictly a global phenomenon: One can always choose a connection $\nabla'$ with the same geodesics for which $M$ locally admits parallel volume form. In the projective differential geometry literature, such connections are sometimes called *special*. See my answer to the question linked above for more about this picture.

Comment: If a connection is metric but not torsion-free, does it admit a parallel volume form? I only ask because in your second last paragraph, you are talking about the Levi-Civita connection rather than an arbitrary metric connection.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes, and for the same reason. I've adjust that paragraph to reflect that generality (which I now see was already present in your original comment). Thanks for the helpful comment.

Comment: I know it has been some time since I asked this, but I wonder if you could shed light on the following: You showed that a parallel top-degree multivector exist (locally) iff the curvature is *trace-free*. This looks very similar to two other instances in geometry where volume-preservation is connected to vanishing trace: (1) $\mathfrak{sl}$ is the Lie algebra of $\mathbb{SL}$. (2) The flow of a vector field $X$ preserves a volume form iff its divergence $\text{tr}(\nabla X)=0$ (again vanishing trace). In fact, (2) can essentially be reduced to (1).

Comment: Do you see a clear analogy between these situations and the current setting? Perhaps your answer could be somehow phrased in terms of structure group ($G$-structures and their reductions) or in some other way? Maybe there is a way to reduce the question to the known facts $(1),(2)$ I mentioned above. Somehow your (very nice) proof seems a bit different; you showed the curvature of the induced connection on $\Lambda_k(E)$ is the trace of the curvature of the original connection.

Comment: These can all viewed as consequences of the fact that the trace operation can be viewed as the linearization of the determinant (the latter of which is exactly what is preserved by the special linear group): For a smooth curve $A : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to M(n, \Bbb R)$ satisfying $A(0) = I$, we have $A(t) = I + t \operatorname{tr} A(0) + O(t^2)$.

Comment: The condition is also equivalent to the existence of a (locally) parallel $\mathrm{SL}(n, \Bbb R)$-structure, that is, a reduction of the frame bundle of $E$ to $\mathrm{SL}(n, \Bbb R)$ invariant under parallel translation.

Comment: I just noticed that the formula two comments up is garbled; the correct statement is:

For a smooth curve $A: (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to M(n, \Bbb R)$ satisfying $A(0) = I$, we have $$\det A(t) = 1 + t \operatorname{tr} A(0) + O(t^2) .$$